# OAuth2 401 Unauthorized from resource server

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, owin, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I tried to implement OAuth2 authentication and authorization. I have an authorization server and a resource server. The client logs in to the authorization server (sends the username and password to the authorization server) and the authorization server returns an access_token. The client uses the access_token in order to ask for any resource with an [Authorize] tag from the resource_server.

The authentication part (sending credentials to the authorization server and getting back an access_token) works fine. I get a valid JWT token. **The problem is that the resource server does not recognize the access_token. Everytime the client sends a request to get a resource that has an [Authorize] tag I get : '401 Unauthorized Authorization has been denied for this request'**.

This is a list of things I tried/verified:

1. I checked for Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth to be the exact same version on both resource and authorization server (version 2.1.0)
2. I checked for the client_id and secret to be the exact same version on both resource and authorization server
3. I made sure that there is the exact same machine key on both resource and authorization server (same values in web.config files and in iis)
4. I checked for iis to have anonymous authentication enabled (and any other form of authentication disabled)
5. I have CORS enabled everywhere
6. The both servers are on the same machine.
7. I verified the request to the resource server and the token is sent in the Authorization header like this: `Authorization:JWT eyJ0eXAiO.......JuRpuf6yWg`
8. I sent the same request with postman, but I get the same response

My implementation is based on these two tutorials:

1. http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/
2. http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

This is the Startup.cs class in my resource server:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Web.Api.App_Start;

namespace Web.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware((newAutofacContainer())
                  .ConfigureContainer(config));
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var issuer = "http://localhost:81/Auth.Server";
            var audience = "AUDIENCE";
            var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("SECRET");
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new 
                          IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                          {
                             new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, 
                                secret)
                           },
                    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = context =>
                        {
                            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new 
                               System.Security
                               .Claims.Claim("newCustomClaim", "newValue"));
                            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [SOLVED]: It should be Authorization:**Bearer** eyJ0eXAiO.......JuRpuf6yWg (Bearer NOT JWT!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]: It should be `Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiO.......JuRpuf6yWg` (**Bearer** NOT JWT!)